# Swagger 2 Issue - Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa

I was using a tutorial and everything was working fine until I started dealing with swagger 2 dependencies.
I wonder now if there is a way to fix this.

SwaggerConfig:

```java
package com.animes.apirest.config;

import springfox.documentation.swagger2.annotations.EnableSwagger2;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import springfox.documentation.builders.RequestHandlerSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.service.ApiInfo;
import springfox.documentation.service.Contact;
import springfox.documentation.service.VendorExtension;
import springfox.documentation.spi.DocumentationType;
import springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.Docket;


import static springfox.documentation.builders.PathSelectors.regex;

import java.util.ArrayList;

@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {
    
    @Bean
    public Docket atividadeApi() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.atividades.apirest"))
                .paths(regex("/api.*"))
                .build()
                .apiInfo(metaInfo());
    }

    private ApiInfo metaInfo() {

        ApiInfo apiInfo = new ApiInfo(
                "Atividades API REST",
                "API REST de cadastro de atividades.",
                "1.0",
                "Terms of Service",
                new Contact("João VR", "www.una.br/",
                        " "),
                "Apache License Version 2.0",
                "https://www.apache.org/licesen.html", new ArrayList<VendorExtension>()
        );

        return apiInfo;
    }
}
```

pom.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.animes</groupId>
    <artifactId>apirest</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>apirest</name>
    <description>Anime project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>20.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Error:

```
19:07:08.137 [Thread-0] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader - Created RestartClassLoader org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader@43899316

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.6.0)

2021-11-21 19:07:08.606  INFO 9840 --- [  restartedMain] com.animes.apirest.ApirestApplication    : Starting ApirestApplication using Java 16.0.2 on DESKTOP-TIGCP3C with PID 9840 (C:\Program Files (x86)\eclipse\Workspace\apirest\target\classes started by Pichau in C:\Program Files (x86)\eclipse\Workspace\apirest)
2021-11-21 19:07:08.607  INFO 9840 --- [  restartedMain] com.animes.apirest.ApirestApplication    : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2021-11-21 19:07:08.679  INFO 9840 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2021-11-21 19:07:08.680  INFO 9840 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
2021-11-21 19:07:09.807  INFO 9840 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2021-11-21 19:07:09.895  INFO 9840 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 71 ms. Found 1 JPA repository interfaces.
2021-11-21 19:07:10.790  INFO 9840 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2021-11-21 19:07:10.813  INFO 9840 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2021-11-21 19:07:10.813  INFO 9840 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.55]
2021-11-21 19:07:10.965  INFO 9840 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2021-11-21 19:07:10.966  INFO 9840 --- [  restartedMain] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2286 ms
2021-11-21 19:07:11.194  INFO 9840 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2021-11-21 19:07:11.245  INFO 9840 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.6.1.Final
2021-11-21 19:07:11.427  INFO 9840 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
2021-11-21 19:07:11.536  INFO 9840 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2021-11-21 19:07:11.746  INFO 9840 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2021-11-21 19:07:11.776  INFO 9840 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL10Dialect
2021-11-21 19:07:12.466  INFO 9840 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2021-11-21 19:07:12.475  INFO 9840 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2021-11-21 19:07:13.074  WARN 9840 --- [  restartedMain] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2021-11-21 19:07:13.266  INFO 9840 --- [  restartedMain] pertySourcedRequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped URL path [/v2/api-docs] onto method [springfox.documentation.swagger2.web.Swagger2Controller#getDocumentation(String, HttpServletRequest)]
2021-11-21 19:07:13.497  INFO 9840 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
2021-11-21 19:07:13.717  INFO 9840 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2021-11-21 19:07:13.718  INFO 9840 --- [  restartedMain] d.s.w.p.DocumentationPluginsBootstrapper : Context refreshed
2021-11-21 19:07:13.740  INFO 9840 --- [  restartedMain] d.s.w.p.DocumentationPluginsBootstrapper : Found 1 custom documentation plugin(s)
2021-11-21 19:07:13.744  WARN 9840 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'documentationPluginsBootstrapper'; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.condition.PatternsRequestCondition.toString()" because the return value of "springfox.documentation.spi.service.contexts.Orderings.patternsCondition(springfox.documentation.RequestHandler)" is null
2021-11-21 19:07:13.747  INFO 9840 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2021-11-21 19:07:13.751  INFO 9840 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2021-11-21 19:07:13.760  INFO 9840 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
2021-11-21 19:07:13.782  INFO 9840 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2021-11-21 19:07:13.796  INFO 9840 --- [  restartedMain] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2021-11-21 19:07:13.826 ERROR 9840 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'documentationPluginsBootstrapper'; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.condition.PatternsRequestCondition.toString()" because the return value of "springfox.documentation.spi.service.contexts.Orderings.patternsCondition(springfox.documentation.RequestHandler)" is null
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:181) ~[spring-context-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:54) ~[spring-context-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:356) ~[spring-context-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:155) ~[spring-context-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:123) ~[spring-context-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:935) ~[spring-context-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:586) ~[spring-context-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:730) ~[spring-boot-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:412) ~[spring-boot-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:302) ~[spring-boot-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1301) ~[spring-boot-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1290) ~[spring-boot-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at com.animes.apirest.ApirestApplication.main(ApirestApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.condition.PatternsRequestCondition.toString()" because the return value of "springfox.documentation.spi.service.contexts.Orderings.patternsCondition(springfox.documentation.RequestHandler)" is null
    at springfox.documentation.spi.service.contexts.Orderings$8.compare(Orderings.java:112) ~[springfox-spi-2.9.2.jar:null]
    at springfox.documentation.spi.service.contexts.Orderings$8.compare(Orderings.java:109) ~[springfox-spi-2.9.2.jar:null]
    at com.google.common.collect.ComparatorOrdering.compare(ComparatorOrdering.java:37) ~[guava-20.0.jar:na]
    at java.base/java.util.TimSort.countRunAndMakeAscending(TimSort.java:355) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:220) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1232) ~[na:na]
    at com.google.common.collect.Ordering.sortedCopy(Ordering.java:855) ~[guava-20.0.jar:na]
    at springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.WebMvcRequestHandlerProvider.requestHandlers(WebMvcRequestHandlerProvider.java:57) ~[springfox-spring-web-2.9.2.jar:null]
    at springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.DocumentationPluginsBootstrapper$2.apply(DocumentationPluginsBootstrapper.java:138) ~[springfox-spring-web-2.9.2.jar:null]
    at springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.DocumentationPluginsBootstrapper$2.apply(DocumentationPluginsBootstrapper.java:135) ~[springfox-spring-web-2.9.2.jar:null]
    at com.google.common.collect.Iterators$7.transform(Iterators.java:750) ~[guava-20.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.common.collect.TransformedIterator.next(TransformedIterator.java:47) ~[guava-20.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.common.collect.TransformedIterator.next(TransformedIterator.java:47) ~[guava-20.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.common.collect.MultitransformedIterator.hasNext(MultitransformedIterator.java:52) ~[guava-20.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.common.collect.MultitransformedIterator.hasNext(MultitransformedIterator.java:50) ~[guava-20.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList.copyOf(ImmutableList.java:249) ~[guava-20.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList.copyOf(ImmutableList.java:209) ~[guava-20.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.common.collect.FluentIterable.toList(FluentIterable.java:614) ~[guava-20.0.jar:na]
    at springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.DocumentationPluginsBootstrapper.defaultContextBuilder(DocumentationPluginsBootstrapper.java:111) ~[springfox-spring-web-2.9.2.jar:null]
    at springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.DocumentationPluginsBootstrapper.buildContext(DocumentationPluginsBootstrapper.java:96) ~[springfox-spring-web-2.9.2.jar:null]
    at springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.DocumentationPluginsBootstrapper.start(DocumentationPluginsBootstrapper.java:167) ~[springfox-spring-web-2.9.2.jar:null]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:178) ~[spring-context-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
```

Searching about I tried to change versions to 2.8.0, 2.7.0, 3.0.0... also returns error.
The application is an apirest with task list activities.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Springboot 2.6.0 / Spring fox 3 - Failed to start bean 'documentationPluginsBootstrapper'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70036953/springboot-2-6-0-spring-fox-3-failed-to-start-bean-documentationpluginsboot)

Comment: No, I already checked before I asked

Comment: I described how I solved it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72235752/cannot-invoke-org-springframework-web-servlet-mvc-condition-patternsrequestcond/74186904#74186904

Comment: @Nophi, were you able to solve it.. I am also getting same error for springfox 3.0.0 and springboot 2.7.14

Answer (score 16):

try upgrade version of springfox, add spring fox starter and remove `@EnableSwagger2`

Dependencies to be added

```xml
        <!--springfox dependencies for api documentations in swagger -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

Remove anotations `@EnableSwagger2`

```
@Configuration
// @EnableSwagger2 // remove this annotation
public class SwaggerConfig { ... }
```

try on this link if there is no override changing in default path

```
http://localhost:{port}/swagger-ui/index.html
```

Comment: I did exactly as you told me, but I still get the error: https://www.codepile.net/pile/VK0Z1k7a

Comment: Do you have at least one of endpoint fits to your pattern? `.apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.atividades.apirest"))` and `paths(regex("/api.*"))`. try remove this pattern and add `@Api on any controller or @ApiOperation on any method` just for testing

Comment: Sorry, I got a little confused. These are the other api codes: https://www.codepile.net/pile/lKomr4P7 and https://www.codepile.net/pile/G6prAae7

Comment: Have you tried remove your pattern path for testing? try replace for this `.apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.animes.apirest.resources")).paths(PathSelectors.any())` in your `SwaggerConfig`

Comment: Yes, but didn't work https://www.codepile.net/pile/WPqVrxEB

Answer (score 12):

I have solved this issue in the Latest Spring Boot 2.6.7 version by following steps. Anyone can check who is facing this issue in 2.6.7 version.

1. **Comment/Remove actuator dependency in pom.xml file**

```
    <!--        <dependency>-->
    <!--            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>-->
    <!--            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>-->
    <!--        </dependency>-->
```

2. **Add swagger dependency in pom.xml file**

```
     <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

3. **Swagger Configuration class change to**

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;
import springfox.documentation.builders.ApiInfoBuilder;
import springfox.documentation.builders.PathSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.builders.RequestHandlerSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.service.ApiInfo;
import springfox.documentation.service.Contact;
import springfox.documentation.spi.DocumentationType;
import springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.Docket;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class SwaggerConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2).select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.companyname.app"))
                .paths(PathSelectors.regex("/.*"))
                .build().apiInfo(apiInfoMetaData());
    }

    private ApiInfo apiInfoMetaData() {

        return new ApiInfoBuilder().title("NAME OF SERVICE")
                .description("API Endpoint Decoration")
                .contact(new Contact("Dev-Team", "https://www.dev-team.com/", "dev-team@gmail.com"))
                .license("Apache 2.0")
                .licenseUrl("http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html")
                .version("1.0.0")
                .build();
    }

}
```

4. **Swagger apis URL**

My case

```
http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/index.html
```

Your case if you different port and project context path

```
http://localhost:{port}/your-context-path/swagger-ui/index.html
```

Answer (score 10):

The springfox plugin is not compatible with PathPattern-based matching in Spring MVC which has replaced the previous Ant-based matching in the Spring Boot default settings. See e.g. here

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/70037507/15496965
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/69814964/15496965

You can try to set `spring.mvc.pathmatch.matching-strategy=ant_path_matcher` to flip that property back to its previous default value. But this won't help if you use actuators which are not effected by that property.

You can try to force the actuators back to Ant-based matching as explained in the second post. But I'd really not recommend that. Instead, you can use Spring Boot <= 2.5 for the moment or migrate to `springdoc`.

Comment: I had to remove actuator dependency , and add the ant_path_matcher property to get this work.
Else, if It's needed to keep actuator then a downgrade to spring boot 5.2.7 is a MUST.

Answer (score 4):

I know this does not solve your problem directly, but consider moving to [springdoc](https://springdoc.org/). Springfox is so buggy at this point that is a pain to use. I've moved to `springdoc` 2 years ago because of its Spring WebFlux support and I am very happy about it. Additionally, it also supports Kotlin Coroutines, which I am not sure Springfox does.

If you decide to migrate, `springdoc` even has a [migration guide](https://springdoc.org/#migrating-from-springfox).

Additionally, you are already using Spring Boot 2.6, which is very very recent (its [release notes](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.6-Release-Notes) are from a couple of hours ago) and thus `springdoc` and `Springfox` might not support it already. So I would also suggest you use Spring Boot 2.5.7 instead.

Comment: Even the docs are better !

Answer (score 3):

Just add this configuration to your application.properties

```
spring.mvc.pathmatch.matching-strategy = ANT_PATH_MATCHER
```

then Run your application.

You need to edit one part, the base package name. As shown in the screenshot my base package name.
[my package name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RvLEJ.png)

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig2 {
    @Bean
    public Docket docket() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .enable(true)
                .apiInfo(new ApiInfoBuilder()
                        .title("Swagger Super")
                        .description("Swagger Description details")
                        .version("1.0").build())
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.example.swagger.controller"))
                .paths(PathSelectors.any()).build();
    }
}
```

OR

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig2 {
    @Bean
    public Docket docket() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .enable(true)
                .apiInfo(new ApiInfoBuilder()
                        .title("Swagger Super")
                        .description("Swagger Description details")
                        .version("1.0").build())
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.withClassAnnotation(Api.class))
                .paths(PathSelectors.any()).build();
    }
}
```

And the Swagger Dependencies

```
         <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Try like this, I hope it will work

**Note:** SNAPSHOT, M1, M2, M3, and M4 releases typically WORK IN PROGRESS. The Spring team is still working on them, Recommend NOT using them.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error, but I get down the  **org.springframework.boot** to 2.5.8, and I had it on 2.7.1.

```
<parent>
     <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
     <version>2.5.8</version>
     <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

And the Swagger Dependencies

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

And It works!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
    It should be added, when i add it resolved  
      <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
      </dependency>

show the below all swagger dependency
    <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-schema</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add @Enablewebmvc in @Configuration class

and remove all other dependencies and include only below one for swagger

```
Add @Enablewebmvc in @Configuration class
```

and remove all other dependencies and include only below one for swagger

```
   <dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
     <version>3.0.0</version>
   </dependency> "
```

Answer (score 0):

Just adding below to your application.properties works like magic

```
spring.mvc.pathmatch.matching-strategy = ANT_PATH_MATCHER
```