# Cannot invoke "org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.condition.PatternsRequestCondition.getPatterns()" because "this.condition" is null

Tags: java, spring-boot, springdoc, springdoc-openapi-ui

I'm trying to run Springdoc with Spring Boot 2.6.7.

Configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class SwaggerConfiguration {
  
  @Bean
  public GroupedOpenApi publicApi() {
    return GroupedOpenApi.builder()
            .group("springshop-public")
            .pathsToMatch("/public/**")
            .build();
  }
}
```

Error stack:

```
00:50:54.956 [main] ERROR SpringApplication[reportFailure:830] - Application run failed
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'documentationPluginsBootstrapper'; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.condition.PatternsRequestCondition.getPatterns()" because "this.condition" is null
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:181)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:54)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:356)
    at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:155)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:123)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:935)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:586)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:740)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:415)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1312)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1301)
    at com.atlas.psp.AtlasRouterApplication.main(AtlasRouterApplication.java:53)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.condition.PatternsRequestCondition.getPatterns()" because "this.condition" is null
    at springfox.documentation.spring.web.WebMvcPatternsRequestConditionWrapper.getPatterns(WebMvcPatternsRequestConditionWrapper.java:56)
    at springfox.documentation.RequestHandler.sortedPaths(RequestHandler.java:113)
    at springfox.documentation.spi.service.contexts.Orderings.lambda$byPatternsCondition$3(Orderings.java:89)
    at java.base/java.util.Comparator.lambda$comparing$77a9974f$1(Comparator.java:473)
    at java.base/java.util.TimSort.countRunAndMakeAscending(TimSort.java:355)
    at java.base/java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1307)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.sort(ArrayList.java:1721)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.SortedOps$RefSortingSink.end(SortedOps.java:392)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Sink$ChainedReference.end(Sink.java:258)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Sink$ChainedReference.end(Sink.java:258)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Sink$ChainedReference.end(Sink.java:258)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Sink$ChainedReference.end(Sink.java:258)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:510)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:921)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:682)
    at springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.WebMvcRequestHandlerProvider.requestHandlers(WebMvcRequestHandlerProvider.java:81)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1625)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:921)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:682)
    at springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.AbstractDocumentationPluginsBootstrapper.withDefaults(AbstractDocumentationPluginsBootstrapper.java:107)
    at springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.AbstractDocumentationPluginsBootstrapper.buildContext(AbstractDocumentationPluginsBootstrapper.java:91)
    at springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.AbstractDocumentationPluginsBootstrapper.bootstrapDocumentationPlugins(AbstractDocumentationPluginsBootstrapper.java:82)
    at springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.DocumentationPluginsBootstrapper.start(DocumentationPluginsBootstrapper.java:100)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:178)
    ... 14 common frames omitted
```

Is there some way to fix this issue?

Answer (score 38):

This problem is caused by the new PathPatternParser introduced in Spring Boot 2.6.
There are two ways to resolve:

As suggested by @gsan in the comment, add following in your `application.yml` or `application.properties`:

```
spring.mvc.pathmatch.matching-strategy=ant_path_matcher
```

OR

Add the following bean in your config class:

```
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.endpoint.web.CorsEndpointProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.endpoint.web.WebEndpointProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.web.server.ManagementPortType;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.ExposableEndpoint;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.EndpointLinksResolver;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.EndpointMapping;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.EndpointMediaTypes;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.ExposableWebEndpoint;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.WebEndpointsSupplier;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.annotation.ControllerEndpointsSupplier;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.annotation.ServletEndpointsSupplier;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.util.StringUtils;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;

@Bean
public WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping webEndpointServletHandlerMapping(WebEndpointsSupplier webEndpointsSupplier,
        ServletEndpointsSupplier servletEndpointsSupplier, ControllerEndpointsSupplier controllerEndpointsSupplier,
        EndpointMediaTypes endpointMediaTypes, CorsEndpointProperties corsProperties,
        WebEndpointProperties webEndpointProperties, Environment environment) {
    List<ExposableEndpoint<?>> allEndpoints = new ArrayList();
    Collection<ExposableWebEndpoint> webEndpoints = webEndpointsSupplier.getEndpoints();
    allEndpoints.addAll(webEndpoints);
    allEndpoints.addAll(servletEndpointsSupplier.getEndpoints());
    allEndpoints.addAll(controllerEndpointsSupplier.getEndpoints());
    String basePath = webEndpointProperties.getBasePath();
    EndpointMapping endpointMapping = new EndpointMapping(basePath);
    boolean shouldRegisterLinksMapping = this.shouldRegisterLinksMapping(webEndpointProperties, environment,
            basePath);
    return new WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping(endpointMapping, webEndpoints, endpointMediaTypes,
            corsProperties.toCorsConfiguration(), new EndpointLinksResolver(allEndpoints, basePath),
            shouldRegisterLinksMapping, null);
}

private boolean shouldRegisterLinksMapping(WebEndpointProperties webEndpointProperties, Environment environment,
        String basePath) {
    return webEndpointProperties.getDiscovery().isEnabled() && (StringUtils.hasText(basePath)
        || ManagementPortType.get(environment).equals(ManagementPortType.DIFFERENT));
}
```

Reference: [Spring Boot 2.6 + Swagger startup exception: because "this.condition" is null](https://www.springcloud.io/post/2022-05/springboot-swagger/#gsc.tab=0)

Comment: how about in spring mvc with xml file config bros?

Comment: The linked page suggests AND instead of OR

Answer (score 13):

Well, the answer mentioned by @Lyncean Patel is not 100% correct because there is no OR in fixing this. From [this github issue discussion](https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/3462#issuecomment-1010721223) thread, the way to fix it to do both:

1. set `spring.mvc.pathmatch.matching-strategy: ant_path_matcher` in application.properties
2. add this bean

```
@Bean
public WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping webEndpointServletHandlerMapping(WebEndpointsSupplier webEndpointsSupplier, ServletEndpointsSupplier servletEndpointsSupplier, ControllerEndpointsSupplier controllerEndpointsSupplier, EndpointMediaTypes endpointMediaTypes, CorsEndpointProperties corsProperties, WebEndpointProperties webEndpointProperties, Environment environment) {
        List<ExposableEndpoint<?>> allEndpoints = new ArrayList();
        Collection<ExposableWebEndpoint> webEndpoints = webEndpointsSupplier.getEndpoints();
        allEndpoints.addAll(webEndpoints);
        allEndpoints.addAll(servletEndpointsSupplier.getEndpoints());
        allEndpoints.addAll(controllerEndpointsSupplier.getEndpoints());
        String basePath = webEndpointProperties.getBasePath();
        EndpointMapping endpointMapping = new EndpointMapping(basePath);
        boolean shouldRegisterLinksMapping = this.shouldRegisterLinksMapping(webEndpointProperties, environment, basePath);
        return new WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping(endpointMapping, webEndpoints, endpointMediaTypes, corsProperties.toCorsConfiguration(), new EndpointLinksResolver(allEndpoints, basePath), shouldRegisterLinksMapping, null);
    }


private boolean shouldRegisterLinksMapping(WebEndpointProperties webEndpointProperties, Environment environment, String basePath) {
        return webEndpointProperties.getDiscovery().isEnabled() && (StringUtils.hasText(basePath) || ManagementPortType.get(environment).equals(ManagementPortType.DIFFERENT));
    }
```

Comment: Setting only a property didn't help, defining a bean - did

Comment: Hello, I am trying this solution on with the latest spring-boot version i.e 3.1.4, where WebEndpointProperties & CorsEndpointProperties classes are not available. Aware of any alternative for these?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and it worked by adding configuration in `application.yml` AND creating the bean in my `SwaggerConfig` class.

- Springboot 2.7.3
- Java 17
- springfox-boot-starter 3.0.0

When using springdoc-openapi-ui 1.6.11 you only need to add the `application.yml` configuration, as suggested by @Lyncean Patel.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it.
I used spring boot 2.6.12 and swagger3.0
This is the maven configuration：

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

then you should Override WebMvcRequestHandlerProvider.java (Copy and override constructors to filter out abnormal ones)

```
 this.handlerMappings = handlerMappings.stream().filter(mapping -> mapping.getPatternParser() == null)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Everything else stays the same
You need to create a new package in your project home directory with the same name as the class ：**springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins**

good luck！

Answer (score 0):

Consider migration to [springdoc](https://springdoc.org/#migrating-from-springfox)

Migration is such a smooth process and it is unlikely that you encounter bugs like [that](https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/3462).

Comment: But I already us it.

Comment: Sorry, I just assumed it was not springdoc since these kind of bugs usually occur on older versions of swagger.

Comment: could you try to set `spring.mvc.pathmatch.matching-strategy `property to `ant_path_matcher` on your `application.yml` or `application.properties` file

Answer (score 0):

I solved all these issues by removing all springfox dependencies and adding
`implementation 'org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-ui:1.6.12'`to my `build.gradle` file (if you use maven add the corresponding elements) then my SecurityFilterChain bean will look like

```java
...
@Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and()
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/actuator/**").permitAll()
                .and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/swagger-ui/**").permitAll()
                .and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/v3/api-docs/**").permitAll();
        return http.build();
}
...
```

No extra dependencies or configuration is required.

Answer (score 0):

I have used ->implementation("org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.12.0") this dependency in my kts file and there is no use of it for me, after removing
this dependency this error got resolved .
dependency  : Apache Tomcat

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

adding below property worked for me as well.

```
spring.mvc.pathmatch.matching-strategy: ant_path_matcher
```

But it didn't work in another project where spring-actuator dependency was present, so if you're wondering why it's not working, perhaps it's due to actuator's presence. So, I had to drop swagger.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with using spring parent "version 2.6.12" and swagger "3.0.0" version. these are maven configuration.

Note: this helped you when you will face "this.condition.isNull" error.

Answer (score 0):

Above suggested solutions works well i.e to add the bean in config class and adding the property in the application.properties or application.yml . But just to rectify the accepted value for the property added in application.properties or application.yml , should be

```
spring.mvc.pathmatch.matching-strategy=ANT_PATH_MATCHER
```

Below mentioned is not the accepted value .

```
spring.mvc.pathmatch.matching-strategy= ant_path_matcher
```

May be if you are wondering , why your properties file or yml file is showing error .