# How do I enable Swagger API endpoints for a Boot application?

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger

How do enable Swagger endpoints for my microservice? According to [this Baeldung article](https://www.baeldung.com/swagger-2-documentation-for-spring-rest-api), it should be super-easy

First, you add a Springfox dependency

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Second, you include this configuration file

That should be it! No properties, no nothing

```java
@Configuration
public class SpringFoxConfig {                                    
    @Bean
    public Docket api() { 
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)  
          .select()                                  
          .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())              
          .paths(PathSelectors.any())                          
          .build();                                           
    }
}
```

I did exactly¹ that. But I still get an 404 when trying to hit `/v2/api-docs`

Why and how do I finally enable those Swagger endpoints?

## MRE:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>helloworldMRE</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>helloworldMRE</name>
    <description>helloworldMRE</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <image>
                        <builder>paketobuildpacks/builder-jammy-base:latest</builder>
                    </image>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

```java
package com.example.helloworldmre;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class HelloWorld {
    private String message = "Hello World!";
}
```

```java
package com.example.helloworldmre;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class HelloWorldController {
    @GetMapping("/hello-world")
    public HelloWorld getHelloWorld() {
        return new HelloWorld();
    }
}
```

```java
package com.example.helloworldmre;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import springfox.documentation.builders.PathSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.builders.RequestHandlerSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.spi.DocumentationType;
import springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.Docket;

@Configuration
public class SpringFoxConfig {
    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build();
    }
}
```

```java
package com.example.helloworldmre;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class HelloworldMreApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(HelloworldMreApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

¹ *Well, not exactly. The Baeldung article used Boot 2.4.0*

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

*I use Spring Boot 3*

```xml
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
```

*When I tried downgrading to 2.4.0, I started to get this exception so I abandoned that idea*

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 61
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SpringFox doesn't support Springboot v3, the answer is springdoc

```xml
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
   <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
   <version>2.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

[This article](https://medium.com/@f.s.a.kuzman/using-swagger-3-in-spring-boot-3-c11a483ea6dc) should help with the conversion

Comment: Thank you! Though the real project uses Boot 2 unfortunately

Comment: Correct answer (for spring boot 3). Just a hint: current version of springdoc is 2.2.0.

Comment: @Kodigas I'm confused, what do you mean by "the real project"? Your question states you are using Spring Boot 3, its just the Baeldung article that is on Spring Boot 2. These are two very different versions of the framework, you can't implement something on one version and expect it to work seamlessly on the other. If you are on Spring Boot 2, use SpringFox, if you're on Spring Boot 3, use SpringDoc; they aren't interchangeable.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, if you want to stick with `spring-fox`, you can downgrade to Spring Boot 2. It now works

**IMPORTANT!** You really need that magic property (see the second to last snippet). More on that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72235752/cannot-invoke-org-springframework-web-servlet-mvc-condition-patternsrequestcond)

`http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/index.html` works too

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>helloworldservice</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>helloworldservice</name>
    <description>helloworldservice</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <image>
                        <builder>paketobuildpacks/builder-jammy-base:latest</builder>
                    </image>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

```java
package com.example.helloworldmre.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import springfox.documentation.builders.PathSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.builders.RequestHandlerSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.spi.DocumentationType;
import springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.Docket;
import springfox.documentation.swagger2.annotations.EnableSwagger2;

@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SpringFoxConfig {
    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build();
    }
}
```

```java
package com.example.helloworldmre.controller;

import com.example.helloworldmre.data.HelloWorld;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class HelloWorldController {
    @GetMapping("/hello-world")
    public HelloWorld getHelloWorld() {
        return new HelloWorld();
    }
}
```

```java
package com.example.helloworldmre.data;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class HelloWorld {
    private String message = "Hello World!";
}
```

```java
package com.example.helloworldmre;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class HelloworldMreApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(HelloworldMreApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

```
spring.mvc.pathmatch.matching-strategy=ant_path_matcher
```

Response to `http://localhost:8080/v2/api-docs`:

```json
{
  "swagger": "2.0",
  "info": {
    "description": "Api Documentation",
    "version": "1.0",
    "title": "Api Documentation",
    "termsOfService": "urn:tos",
    "contact": {    },
    "license": {
      "name": "Apache 2.0",
      "url": "http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0"
    }
  },
  "host": "localhost:8080",
  "basePath": "/",
  "tags": [
    {
      "name": "basic-error-controller",
      "description": "Basic Error Controller"
    },
    {
      "name": "hello-world-controller",
      "description": "Hello World Controller"
    }
  ],
  "paths": {
    "/error": {
      "get": {
        "tags": [
          "basic-error-controller"
        ],
        "summary": "error",
        "operationId": "errorUsingGET",
        "produces": [
          "*/*"
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "OK",
            "schema": {
              "type": "object",
              "additionalProperties": {
                "type": "object"
              }
            }
          },
          "401": {
            "description": "Unauthorized"
          },
          "403": {
            "description": "Forbidden"
          },
          "404": {
            "description": "Not Found"
          }
        }
      },
      "head": {
        "tags": [
          "basic-error-controller"
        ],
        "summary": "error",
        "operationId": "errorUsingHEAD",
        "consumes": [
          "application/json"
        ],
        "produces": [
          "*/*"
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "OK",
            "schema": {
              "type": "object",
              "additionalProperties": {
                "type": "object"
              }
            }
          },
          "204": {
            "description": "No Content"
          },
          "401": {
            "description": "Unauthorized"
          },
          "403": {
            "description": "Forbidden"
          }
        }
      },
      "post": {
        "tags": [
          "basic-error-controller"
        ],
        "summary": "error",
        "operationId": "errorUsingPOST",
        "consumes": [
          "application/json"
        ],
        "produces": [
          "*/*"
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "OK",
            "schema": {
              "type": "object",
              "additionalProperties": {
                "type": "object"
              }
            }
          },
          "201": {
            "description": "Created"
          },
          "401": {
            "description": "Unauthorized"
          },
          "403": {
            "description": "Forbidden"
          },
          "404": {
            "description": "Not Found"
          }
        }
      },
      "put": {
        "tags": [
          "basic-error-controller"
        ],
        "summary": "error",
        "operationId": "errorUsingPUT",
        "consumes": [
          "application/json"
        ],
        "produces": [
          "*/*"
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "OK",
            "schema": {
              "type": "object",
              "additionalProperties": {
                "type": "object"
              }
            }
          },
          "201": {
            "description": "Created"
          },
          "401": {
            "description": "Unauthorized"
          },
          "403": {
            "description": "Forbidden"
          },
          "404": {
            "description": "Not Found"
          }
        }
      },
      "delete": {
        "tags": [
          "basic-error-controller"
        ],
        "summary": "error",
        "operationId": "errorUsingDELETE",
        "produces": [
          "*/*"
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "OK",
            "schema": {
              "type": "object",
              "additionalProperties": {
                "type": "object"
              }
            }
          },
          "204": {
            "description": "No Content"
          },
          "401": {
            "description": "Unauthorized"
          },
          "403": {
            "description": "Forbidden"
          }
        }
      },
      "options": {
        "tags": [
          "basic-error-controller"
        ],
        "summary": "error",
        "operationId": "errorUsingOPTIONS",
        "consumes": [
          "application/json"
        ],
        "produces": [
          "*/*"
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "OK",
            "schema": {
              "type": "object",
              "additionalProperties": {
                "type": "object"
              }
            }
          },
          "204": {
            "description": "No Content"
          },
          "401": {
            "description": "Unauthorized"
          },
          "403": {
            "description": "Forbidden"
          }
        }
      },
      "patch": {
        "tags": [
          "basic-error-controller"
        ],
        "summary": "error",
        "operationId": "errorUsingPATCH",
        "consumes": [
          "application/json"
        ],
        "produces": [
          "*/*"
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "OK",
            "schema": {
              "type": "object",
              "additionalProperties": {
                "type": "object"
              }
            }
          },
          "204": {
            "description": "No Content"
          },
          "401": {
            "description": "Unauthorized"
          },
          "403": {
            "description": "Forbidden"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "/hello-world": {
      "get": {
        "tags": [
          "hello-world-controller"
        ],
        "summary": "getHelloWorld",
        "operationId": "getHelloWorldUsingGET",
        "produces": [
          "*/*"
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "OK",
            "schema": {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/HelloWorld"
            }
          },
          "401": {
            "description": "Unauthorized"
          },
          "403": {
            "description": "Forbidden"
          },
          "404": {
            "description": "Not Found"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "definitions": {
    "HelloWorld": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "message": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      },
      "title": "HelloWorld"
    },
    "ModelAndView": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "empty": {
          "type": "boolean"
        },
        "model": {
          "type": "object"
        },
        "modelMap": {
          "type": "object",
          "additionalProperties": {
            "type": "object"
          }
        },
        "reference": {
          "type": "boolean"
        },
        "status": {
          "type": "string",
          "enum": [
            "ACCEPTED",
            "ALREADY_REPORTED",
            "BAD_GATEWAY",
            "BAD_REQUEST",
            "BANDWIDTH_LIMIT_EXCEEDED",
            "CHECKPOINT",
            "CONFLICT",
            "CONTINUE",
            "CREATED",
            "DESTINATION_LOCKED",
            "EXPECTATION_FAILED",
            "FAILED_DEPENDENCY",
            "FORBIDDEN",
            "FOUND",
            "GATEWAY_TIMEOUT",
            "GONE",
            "HTTP_VERSION_NOT_SUPPORTED",
            "IM_USED",
            "INSUFFICIENT_SPACE_ON_RESOURCE",
            "INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE",
            "INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR",
            "I_AM_A_TEAPOT",
            "LENGTH_REQUIRED",
            "LOCKED",
            "LOOP_DETECTED",
            "METHOD_FAILURE",
            "METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED",
            "MOVED_PERMANENTLY",
            "MOVED_TEMPORARILY",
            "MULTIPLE_CHOICES",
            "MULTI_STATUS",
            "NETWORK_AUTHENTICATION_REQUIRED",
            "NON_AUTHORITATIVE_INFORMATION",
            "NOT_ACCEPTABLE",
            "NOT_EXTENDED",
            "NOT_FOUND",
            "NOT_IMPLEMENTED",
            "NOT_MODIFIED",
            "NO_CONTENT",
            "OK",
            "PARTIAL_CONTENT",
            "PAYLOAD_TOO_LARGE",
            "PAYMENT_REQUIRED",
            "PERMANENT_REDIRECT",
            "PRECONDITION_FAILED",
            "PRECONDITION_REQUIRED",
            "PROCESSING",
            "PROXY_AUTHENTICATION_REQUIRED",
            "REQUESTED_RANGE_NOT_SATISFIABLE",
            "REQUEST_ENTITY_TOO_LARGE",
            "REQUEST_HEADER_FIELDS_TOO_LARGE",
            "REQUEST_TIMEOUT",
            "REQUEST_URI_TOO_LONG",
            "RESET_CONTENT",
            "SEE_OTHER",
            "SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE",
            "SWITCHING_PROTOCOLS",
            "TEMPORARY_REDIRECT",
            "TOO_EARLY",
            "TOO_MANY_REQUESTS",
            "UNAUTHORIZED",
            "UNAVAILABLE_FOR_LEGAL_REASONS",
            "UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY",
            "UNSUPPORTED_MEDIA_TYPE",
            "UPGRADE_REQUIRED",
            "URI_TOO_LONG",
            "USE_PROXY",
            "VARIANT_ALSO_NEGOTIATES"
          ]
        },
        "view": {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/View"
        },
        "viewName": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      },
      "title": "ModelAndView"
    },
    "View": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "contentType": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      },
      "title": "View"
    }
  }
}
```