# Swagger is not working after migrating Springfox from v. 2.9.2 to 3.0.0

Tags: java, spring-mvc, swagger, springfox

I am working on Spring MVC and trying to migrate Springfox v. 2.9.2 to 3.0.0. When I change the version to 3.0.0, it gives me error:

> org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'documentationPluginsBootstrapper'; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class springfox.documentation.schema.Types

Here is my dependency:

```xml
<swagger-version>3.0.0</swagger-version>
<swagger-version-ui>3.0.0</swagger-version-ui>
<swagger-annotations>2.1.11</swagger-annotations>

<dependency>
  <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
  <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
  <version>${swagger-version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
  <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
  <version>${swagger-version-ui}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
  <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
  <version>${swagger-annotations}</version>
</dependency>
```

How to properly configure Springfox 3.0.0 in Spring MVC?

Comment: [Migrating from existing 2.x version](https://springfox.github.io/springfox/docs/current/#migrating-from-existing-2-x-version), welcome! ;*

Comment: Consider moving to `springdoc` instead of using `Springfox`. You can find more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69108852/16572295).

Comment: @JoãoDias after integrating swagger page is showing 404, any idea about this, my project is not springboot application

Comment: Unfortunately no, I've always used without any issues in Spring Boot applications.

Answer (score 0):

Many resources on the Internet say that as long as the two packages `springfox-swagger2` and `springfox-swagger-ui` are available. I found that if only these two packages are used to run the project, it will report `ClassnotFoundException` or `NoSuchMethodException`. Add little by little, and finally the actual imported package is as follows:

```
<spring.version>5.1.5.RELEASE</spring.version>
<spring.plugin.version>2.0.0.RELEASE</spring.plugin.version>
<swagger.version>3.0.0</swagger.version>
 <!-- swagger2 jar-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>${swagger.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>${swagger.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-common</artifactId>
            <version>${swagger.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${swagger.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-core</artifactId>
            <version>${swagger.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-spi</artifactId>
            <version>${swagger.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--spring plugin,configure swagger-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.plugin</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-plugin-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.plugin.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

I didn't know the specific reason. But I tried it, if any package is missing, an error will be reported.