# connect spring boot to swagger

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, springfox

I am trying to connect my e-commerce project backend to swagger2. I have installed all the dependencies, yet I still cannot do it.

This is the dependency declared in my pom.xml file:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.2</version>
</dependency>
        <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

This is one of my user controller files:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
@CrossOrigin
public class UserController {
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @GetMapping("/")
    public List<User> GetUsers() {
        return userRepository.findAll();
    }
    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public User GetUser(@PathVariable String id) {
        return userRepository.findById(id).orElse(null);
    }
    @PostMapping("/")
    public User postMethodName(@RequestBody User user) {
        return userRepository.save(user);
    }
    @PutMapping("/")
    public User PutMapping(@RequestBody User newUser) {
        User oldUser = userRepository.findById(newUser.getId()).orElse(null);
        oldUser.setName(newUser.getName());
        oldUser.setEmail(newUser.getEmail());
        oldUser.setPassword(newUser.getPassword());
        userRepository.save(oldUser);
        return oldUser;
    }
    @DeleteMapping("/{id}")
    public String DeleteUser(@PathVariable String id) {
        userRepository.deleteById(id);
        return id;
    }
}
```

This is the code of my main application:

```java
package com.omazon.ecommerce;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

import springfox.documentation.swagger2.annotations.EnableSwagger2;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableSwagger2
public class ECommerceApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ECommerceApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Lastly, this is what I declared in the `application.properties` file:

```
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://localhost:27017/e-commerce
```

This is the picture of the error I got:

[image]

Comment: when I run it in the local host , it says that it refused to connect

Comment: Not sure whether I make myself clear , but if u guys have any questions just raise it here

Comment: Consider moving to `springdoc`. You can find some details about it at https://stackoverflow.com/a/69108852/16572295.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swagger2's usage seems to require (or at least often includes) the concept of a `Docket` api via an instantiation such as `new Docket()` or `new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)`. I don't see that in your code snippets, so wonder if that may be one issue.

Per the swagger docs, `Docket` is Springfox’s *primary api configuration mechanism*.

Specifically, [this](https://springfox.github.io/springfox/docs/snapshot/#docket-spring-java-configuration) section regarding configuration may be helpful. Note the `Docket` instantiation:

```
...
@Bean //Don't forget the @Bean annotation
public Docket customImplementation(){
   return new Docket()
         .apiInfo(apiInfo());
         //... more options available
...
```

There's also a more complete example in those same docs [here](https://springfox.github.io/springfox/docs/snapshot/#springfox-spring-mvc-and-spring-boot).

For reference, there's another usage example in [this](https://www.baeldung.com/swagger-2-documentation-for-spring-rest-api) tutorial.